# Apache PHP shell_exec screen

Tags: apache2, php, screen

I encountered a weird problem after switching from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I am running a screen session from Apache/PHP like this:

```
shell_exec("sudo screen -L -A -d -S NameOfScreen -m /home/script.sh");
```

And everytime I restart my apache server the screen is closing. I never had this problem before and using google to solve my question is not working either.

I know from past experience I solved this problem on Windows by running apache as console and using PSTools for the executables.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by not using mod_php and moving to php-fpm fastcgi